# What is the difference between following two snippets?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
char *t=new char();
```

and

```
char *t=new char[102];
```

as my code was accepted by using the latter one?

```
//BISHOPS SPOJ
```

Answer (score 6):

```
char *t=new char();
```

Allocates memory for a single character, and calls the default constructor.

```
char *t=new char[102];
```

Creates an array of 102 `char`s and calls the default constructor.

As the default constructor for POD types is nothing, the difference is the amount of memory allocated (single char vs array of char)

Comment: The first `char` is zero-initialized. The array is not.

Answer (score 4):

Actually both are pointers on `char`, but second is pointer to `char` array.

Which allows you to store 102 characters into the array.

```
char *t=new char[102];

  0   1   2   3       101
+---+---+---+---+ ... +---+
|   |   |   |         |   |
+---+---+---+---+ ... +---+
  ^
  |
  -----------------------------+---+
                               | * |
                               +---+
                                 t
```

It allows you to dereference these indexes 0-101.

---

While first one allows you to store only one character.

```
char *t=new char();
  0
+---+
|   |
+---+
  ^
  |
  -----------------------------+---+
                               | * |
                               +---+
                                 t
```

Where dereferencing other index than `0` would lead to access outside of bounds and undefined behavior.

---

**Deleting**

To delete an character `char *t=new char();`

```
delete t;
```

Where to delete an array `char *t=new char[102];` you have to write empty brackes, to explicitly say its an array.

```
delete [] t;
```

---

Same with these codes

```
char *t = new char[10];  // Poitner to array of 10 characters

char *t = new char(10);  // Pointer to one character with value of 10
```

---

**Memory initialialization**

```
char *t = new char();      // default initialized (ie nothing happens)
char *t = new char(10);    // zero    initialized (ie set to 0)
```

**Arrays**:

```
char *t = new char[10];   // default initialized (ie nothing happens)
char *t = new char[10](); // zero    initialized (ie all elements set to 0)
```